# What are *.dll.s files and what are they used for?

Tags: dll, assembly, mono, unity-game-engine, file-format

I am currently working on an iOS project using the Unity framework.

When I export an Xcode project from Unity, there are a whole bunch of files exported.
Besides some source files, there are also .dll files for the Mono project.

But there are also **.dll.s** files.
For troubleshooting, it would be great to know what they are used for.
There is one **.dll.s** file for every dll, so it could be some sort of source which is compiled into the dll?

When there are exceptions somewhere in the code, Xcode often jumps into one of these .dll.s files and it looks as if they contain some sort of assembly code.

Directions would be nice, Google isn't really helpful here ...

TIA,

best regards,

Flo

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Comment: @LexLi Mac user here, never heard of MS Unity before. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Fully understand. It is strange that Unity 3D re-branded to Unity. Well, the rule is when you add a tag to your question, please spare some time review the tag information by hanging the cursor over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're the IL code in the dll files compiled into arm assembly. This is the code that eventually end up in the final app binary.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language - it's what C# and VB compiles into.

Comment: Cool, thanks very much. And how are they related to the dll? Do I need the dll files also? Will read into this a bit more.

Comment: You still need the dll files too, among other things the resources are still stored in them.